# Accessing php file function from cordova project

Tags: php, cordova

I am new in  Cordova and i created a project to use data from my local server database PHPMyadmin but when i call this, it alert the error part . this my ajax call:

```
        var formURL = "localhost/jobs/mobile/home/searchJobs/";

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data : "&data=12",
            success:function(response)
            {   alert('success part');
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR)
            {
                alert('the error part');
                //alert($.parseJSON(jqXHR));     
            }
        });
```

Thanks, your suggestions will solve my problem.

Comment: PHP code is correct no problem with it

Comment: It works from browser but not working with emulator

Comment: Try `10.0.2.2` instead of localhost it should work

Comment: Please add second parameter for your error callback such as _status_ and then inside the callback, call `alert('error code: ' + status);`